# Google Plus PHP Login

Tags: php, authentication, google-plus

I am trying to make google+ login with php, its working but there is this piece of code:

```
if(isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    header('Location:'.filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

and when I put only localhost/?code in the url then it gives me this error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Invalid code'
```

Is there a way to handle this ?

Comment: I hope you must have set callback url in google+ API. if that is different from what you are trying to mention then it will throw errors.

Comment: Are you using like this localhost/?code=your_code ?

Comment: Yes, i am using localhost/folder/?code=my_code, its working, but when i  manually enter in the url only ?code it will throw this error.